# Asp.net login redirect not working

Tags: asp.net

Dear all programming stalwarts ,

I would be very grateful if you can assist regarding  the following .My website development  phase ASP NET 2012 has 3 roles(Admin,Members and Organisations).My login cs page has redirect to different pages in accordance to roles.When I test every user and role I am being  directed to another page .The same page is not the one implemented in login cs.

I have tried to remove the code behind the login cs to understand the error ,debug and view under chosen browser .Still it is pointing to registration .

Here is what I have done so far

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Administrator"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/SiteAdm.aspx");
        }
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Members"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~members/MembersControlPanel.aspx");
        }
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "VolOrganisations"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/VolOrganisations/Opportunities.aspx");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event named authenticated, in this event the authentication is complete and you can check your user if is in an specific role and make the redirection, like you did in your code.